# How to configure Deployment Source in VSCODE?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-appservice

I am trying to deploy basic Angular App to Azure. I installed these extensions:

[image]

When I right click on my AppService, I see this menu:

[image]

If I try to select Configure Deployment source, I do not see any browse option that numerous articles on the web speak about. I see only this:

[image]

How can I enter the directory of my compiled app there? Simple deployment results in my whole uncompiled app being placed into the wwwroot of my AppService.

This is the only confirmation dialog that I see when I click Deploy web app:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**2022 Answer:**

Ran into the same problem in 2022, I solved it by going to the `.vscode` folder in your project directory and editing the `settings.json` file. Delete `"appService.deploySubpath": "<whatever-path>"`. Then try to Deploy to Web App again and you should see the browse that allows you to pick what folder you want to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Before deploying the app to Azure , you need to  build the angular application for production environment by running this command in the terminal tab in Visual Code:

```
ng build --configuration=production
```

Once you login to azure with the extension, you will see all the App Services under your subscription

[image]

Next right click on you App Service application and choose **`“Deploy to Web App”`**, a command popup will be showing on the right. Click on Browse and choose “dist\yourApp” folder under your application and then Click Deploy

Comment: I was running build before writing this question. This does not change anything. Build just creates files in the dist directory. How can I tell that deploying should grab them, but not the whole project? I do not have any "browse" option. This is my question.

Comment: what happens when you click on deploy to web app? you need to click on Deploy to web app not configure source. thats what i have added in the answer

Comment: When I click Deploy it shows a popup dialog with "Deploy" and "Cancel" buttons. When I click Deploy, it start deployment of the whole uncompiled app.

Comment: You need to set the path of the dist folder

Comment: After digging around, it looks like putting settings into .vscode/settings.json is what I need. Although why my UI does not show all these prompts - this is still a mystery.